# Clarification of - Attributes, Characteristics, Services and profiles

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I'm currently trying to get a better understanding of the BLE protocol and I've some questions regarding the structure of GATT - more specifically with regards to what exactly Attributes, Characteristic and Services.
And how these interact and make up a profile.

I have tried to create a visual representation of how I imagine a characteristic is made.
[image]

Unfortunately, I need some respect before I can post an image in the post :(
You need at least 10 reputations to post images.

I hope to get a better clarification of how these things link together to form a full-on service :)

- Thank you

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754183/difference-between-attributes-and-services-in-ble/30755950

Comment: Yes thank you  @bavaza I looked at the 
video - [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZwOrQ6zkzE)
and webpages - [link](https://atadiat.com/en/e-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-101-tutorial-intensive-introduction/)
in the posts - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793182/smart-bluetooth-gatt-vs-att-what-are-the-differences-between-them/52570283#52570283)
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793182/smart-bluetooth-gatt-vs-att-what-are-the-differences-between-them/52570283#52570283)
And was able to piece together an answer to my own question via this information, thank you.